# Why is my ContentView Style working only once through the page?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following style defined in my Content Page:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentView}" x:Key="ColorScaleGordura">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="15,0,15,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="15" HeightRequest="30">
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorScaleRed}" Style="{StaticResource NutrientColorFrameStyle}">
                                <Label Text="G" Style="{StaticResource NutrientInitialsStyle}"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorScaleDarkOrange}" Style="{StaticResource NutrientColorFrameStyle}">
                                <Label Text="G" Style="{StaticResource NutrientInitialsStyle}"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorScaleOrange}" Style="{StaticResource NutrientColorFrameStyle}">
                                <Label Text="G" Style="{StaticResource NutrientInitialsStyle}"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorScaleYellow}" Style="{StaticResource NutrientColorFrameStyle}">
                                <Label Text="G" Style="{StaticResource NutrientInitialsStyle}"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorScaleLightGreen}" Style="{StaticResource NutrientColorFrameStyle}">
                                <Label Text="G" Style="{StaticResource NutrientInitialsStyle}"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorScaleGreen}" Style="{StaticResource NutrientColorFrameStyle}">
                                <Label Text="G" Style="{StaticResource NutrientInitialsStyle}"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorScaleDarkGreen}" Style="{StaticResource NutrientColorFrameStyle}">
                                <Label Text="G" Style="{StaticResource NutrientInitialsStyle}"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

This is what it is supose to look like:

[image]

I've made this as a Style because I need it to repeat a lot of times through the page. I am using it like this:

```
<ContentView Style="{StaticResource ColorScaleGordura}"/>
```

And it works! But only once. No matter where in my page I paste the code line above, only one will work (usually the one further down the page). If I do something like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="test1"/>
    <ContentView Style="{StaticResource ColorScaleGordura}"/>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="test2"/>
        <ContentView Style="{StaticResource ColorScaleGordura}"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="test3"/>
            <ContentView Style="{StaticResource ColorScaleGordura}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't know why this acts like that but you can just do a different thing, you have repeating controls just create a custom control then just use it <MyStyledControl/>

Comment: Similar issue in *WPF Application* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307989/wpf-button-style-wont-apply-to-second-button

Comment: @NickKovalsky thank you, using a custom control solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, you're trying to add the same `Content` to more than one `ContentView`. Elements (present in Style) cannot be added to more than one Logical Parents. To avoid this, you can set `x:Shared="False"` to your `Style`.

But i believe `x:Shared` only works in WPF application. I don't think there is other alternate for `Xamarin.Forms`. If your intention is repeat the `StackLayout`, you can try using `RepeaterView` with `DataTemplate` to achieve the expected.

There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355992/xamarin-forms-xshared) available to do this, but the `CreateContent()` method seems to be unavailable. Still, you can make it working if above solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I've ended up creating a custom control as suggested by Nick Kovalsky